# How to get category Id from order Item?

Tags: magento2, product, category, order-items

I want to get category Id from order Item.

As we aware that we can get `current_category` on the product page.

but how to get that category from `orderItem` object.

We can get Product object via `$orderItem->getProduct()` but,

I am getting `categoryIds()` but I want specific Category Id  where the user 
 come and add that product to cart.

Comment: I think we must save `category id` in `quote_item` while adding the product to cart and then move that `category id` value into `order_item`.

So, for this feature, we need to add the new attribute in quote item and order item.

Answer (score 0):

I think Magento doesn't store that category id further means in quote.

So what easy solution you can do is add a hidden field in addtocart form

So that way you can get detail on `info_buyRequest`

for example `<input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="$catId" >`